# Dynamic column creation based on suffix of dataframe

Tags: r

I have multiple .csv files in a folder with different suffix . For eg :

```
Data_Software
Data_Hardware
Data_Manufacturing ....
```

& similarly many other .csv files. I want to create a new column in each of these data sets say "type" which will contain the suffix of the corresponding file i.e.; all the observations of the type column in the Data_Software should say Software , Data_Hardware should have Hardware.

Can someone help ?

Comment: How are you importing the data? You may want to try: `df1$type <-unlist(lapply(strsplit(df1$firstColumn, split = "_"), function(x) x[[2]]))`; where `df1` is one of the files imported as `data.frame` with column name `firstColumn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wouldn't advise, I might do something like:

```
library(data.table) # need for fread and :=

# Get a list of all files in the directory 
my_dir <- "my_path_here"    
FILES <- list.files(path = my_dir, pattern="*.csv$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

# Read every file
lapply(FILES, function(x) { assign(gsub(paste0(my_dir,"/|\\.csv$|Data_"),"",x),fread(x, header = T)[, Type := gsub(paste0(my_dir,"/|\\.csv$|Data_"),"",x)], envir = .GlobalEnv)})
```

This creates a table for each csv - the table is named the same name as the file, stripping the extension, path, and `Data_`. It also creates a column with the table name on read

Answer (score 0):

Try this, sorry, assumed they were data.frames in your environment, this is not the case, feel free to ignore/suggest changes:

```
# Data frames in your environment
Data_Tom <- iris
Data_Dick <- iris
Data_Harry <- iris

# Get the names of the objects
objs <- ls(pattern = "Data_")

# Add the suffix as a the column
objs <- lapply(objs, 
               function(x){
                 type <- gsub("Data_", "", x)
                 df <- get(x)
                 cbind(df, Type = type)
               })

# Combine them together, you might not need this
combine <- do.call(rbind, objs)
```